# If a theory gets two predictions right, how likely it is that the rest of the predictions are true too?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, string-theory, experimental-physics

The question lucidly defines what I am trying to inquire, so there is no need to elucidate it any further. Another question would be, General/Special Relativity has gotten some predictions right as experimental evidence is backing it up, but is there anything that ***it got wrong?***

Comment: The question in your title and that in your body are almost entirely unrelated to one another. Certainly if you mean to imply that either incarnation of relativity have only been tested a small number of ways you are simply ignoring much of that actual experimental evidence.

Comment: Just one experimental contradiction falsifies a theoretical model and it has to be either modified or abandoned. Special relativity has innumerable confirmations in particle physics, and general relativity in cosmological observations.

Comment: How can we answer this question? If it gets 2 predictions right, how many predictions does it make in total? What were the 2 predictions? Were they significant and/or critical components of the theory? How closely related to the 2 predictions are the other predictions? There is no way to answer the question in the title

Comment: I think you can expand this to if it gets N predictions right, using the rule of succession.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_succession

Comment: But this should be in philosophy or something.  It's a generic question about prediction based on observations.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about epistemology.

Answer (score 2):

The first part of the question

> *If a theory gets two predictions right, how likely it is that the rest of the predictions are true too?* <<

can not be answered since even the wrongest assumption can lead to 2 right predictions (and an uncounted bunch of wrong ones). Two opposite theories can have two simililar predictions which of course does not make them equally propable.

The second part

> *General/Special Relativity has gotten some predictions right as experimental evidence is backing it up, but is there anything that it got wrong?* <<

The realm of plain relativity ends at the quantum border. So when you apply relativity outside its jurisdiction you get results like singularities which likely do not happen in nature.

This however does not disprove relativity, because it still stays valid as a special case of the yet to be found [theory of everything](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_everything). In all experiments done so far relativity was proven at the level it was tested.

Comment: A non working clock still shows the correct time twice a day.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Rule of Succession, the probability is 3/4.  Or (successes+1) divided by (attempts +2).

See:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_succession

This is just an approximation.